# Rmagick, imagemagick: not a correct image and blurry after using -resize method

Tags: image, imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

src image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQIoH.jpg

I have to compress the picture.  But after the compression, the image should not lose much in quality.  When I use the "point" filter, the result has gaps

```
   `convert #{src_path} -filter point -resize #{width}x#{height} #{scaled_path}`
```

Image after resize: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhqHq.jpg

If I use other filters, the picture turns out to be very blurry

blurry image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSmnR.jpg

How can I get a picture with a good quality, but not broken like the image with the point filter above?

Comment: That looks like a bug in your version of ImageMagick. What version are you using? Can you upgrade? Please show your command with actual values for the width and height, so it can be checked in other versions.

Comment: This command works fine for me on IM 6.9.9.50 Q16 Mac OSX. `convert input.png -resize 50% result.png`. So as I mentioned before, it looks like a but in your version of ImageMagick.

Comment: @fmw42. my src image has 355x647, and i should convert to 177x323. my current version is ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2018-06-11.

Comment: @fmw42. and i already updated imagemagick version to ImageMagick 7.0.8-0 Q16 x86_64 2018-06-14, not work still.

Comment: IM 7 uses magick not convert. So this command `magick input.png -resize 50% result.png` works fine for me in IM 7.0.8.0 Q16 HDRI on Mac OSX Sierra. So does `magick input.png -resize 177x323 result.png`.  What is your version of libpng? Perhaps it needs to be upgraded. I am using libpng 1.6.34.